# Download a distant .zip to express server

Tags: node.js, express

I have this link:

> https://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/src-api/vrf-f5660bc3/subad/7471788

which is a .zip archive. And I want to download it to my express server.

Here is what I tried:

```
          request
            .get(distantFile)
            .on('response', function (response) {

                var responseType = (response.headers['content-type'] || '').split(';')[0].trim();
                var ext = mime.extension(responseType);
                console.log(ext)
                filename += '.' + ext;

                var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename)
                            .on('finish', function() {
                                //Download complete
                            })

                this.pipe(fileStream);
            })
```

But it does not work, I guess because it is meant for files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it was simpler than I thought:

```
          await request(uri)
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('abc.zip'))
            .on('close', function () {
                console.log('File written!');
            });
```